# Como dar um postback na pagina asp.net com Javascript ou Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hoje tenho uma function que chama o método toggle quando clico na tag  ele exibe o panel em asp.net contendo um dropdownlist e uma gridview.
Preciso que toda vez se clicar novamente na tag  neste caso para fechar, dê um post nos componentes dropdownlist e gridview voltando os para o estado de escolha.
É possível fazer isso ?
*Meu código está assim hoje:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.a').click(function () {
                $("#pnlSalas").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Por falta de tempo não pude fazer uma resposta a sua pergunta anterior, mas segue um link que contem a resposta da tua pergunta. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863927/lost-focus-method-for-asp-net-textbox

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, valeu @Marciano.Andrade

Comment: @AndreeH Essa é a mesma pergunta que você fez a dias atrás, acho melhor você excluir a outra e manter esta.

Comment: Beleza @Marconi. Ainda não consegui resolver ..

Comment: @AndreeH tem que ser com a função toogle? Estava pensando em fazer no code bind.

Comment: Seguinte Andree, com base na resposta lá da para usar o método `__doPostBack('','')`  no javascript, sendo que esse método é do ajax do próprio .net. Chamando esse método, é executado um post back e os parâmetros do método são enviados no evento page_load da tua pagina.

Comment: no page load tu precisa dai fazer o tratamento desse postback, e é isso que a resposta tá re referindo. FOi isso que você tentou fazer?

Comment: Isso mesmo, e não funcionou ..

Answer (score -1):

Então, a primeira coisa que tem que ficar clara é a seguinte, você quer que quando o cara clicar na "tag" ela dê um post na página ou você quer fazer isso com javascript?

Se você quiser dar um post, você precisa habilitar esse controle "tag" com um runat="server", dessa forma, com um _doPostBack no atributo, você consegue identificar o evento no pageLoad da sua página, e assim fazer o que quiser com seus controles (dropdown e grid) que são controles "server", certo? Essa seria a solução rápida, dai identificando o click no pageLoad, basta alterar os valores. Dropdown.SelectedValue = "0"  e DataGrid.DataSource = New DataTable(0),  por exemplo.

Um exemplo de como pegar o evento _doPostBack do controle que você habilitou no page_Load.

```
 Dim eventTarget As String = IIf(Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET") = Nothing, String.Empty, Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET"))

    'Evento de Pesquisa do botão ENCONTRAR
    If eventTarget.Equals("ValorArgumento") Then
        MetodoAção()
    End If
```

No Html você vai setar o seguinte:

```
 <button onclick="__doPostBack('ValorArgumento', '')" id="idBotao" type="button"></button>
```

Agora, se você quiser fazer isso com javascript, sem post, você tem que criar uma função javascript, encontrar os elementos (pode ser com chaves jquery) e atribuir a propriedade val() pro dropdown.